# Thrift Client can't connect

Tags: thrift

I have a thrift server and client that work when running on the same computer, but when I run the client on a different computer (using the IP of the server computer), the client can't connect. Both computers are linux. Any ideas?

---

EDIT: if I go on my server computer and check activity on certain IPs using `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep [ip]:[port]`, I get:

172.18.18.106:9090 -> nothing

:9090 -> `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10642/server`

Is there a way to change 0.0.0.0 to my ip?

Comment: Exception messages, error logs, any other information?

Comment: just the standard `TSocket::open() connect() <Host: [ip] Port: 9090> Connection refused` message (apache thrift always gives this when the client can't connect)

Comment: You're starting the server on the other computer, and on that port?

Comment: yeah, I can tell because if I start the client from the server computer, it works. Do you think it might be a firewall or something?

Comment: A firewall seems likely, what's between the two machines on the network? And when you see things bind to `0.0.0.0` it means they are binding to all addresses, ie they accept connections from both local and remote addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. You should bind your Thrift server with the IP of your server computer.

Another solution is checking if any firewall rules block port 9090 from accessing from outside network. You should do a telnet from your client computer:

```
telnet 172.18.18.106 9090
```

If it can connect, you're done.

Comment: "You should bind your Thrift server with the IP of your server computer.", how to do that ?

Comment: you need to know what you ipv4 is, then pass that when instantiating your thrift server.. @amarnathchatterjee

Answer (score 0):

Offlately i got into similar issue with apache hbase.2.1.2. I had setup hbase and started thrift server. It opened port 9090 and 9095. I can connect to them locally but not remotely. As i can telnet both ports remotely, firewall issues are ironed out. I found the issue to be in timeout settings. Apparently it seems that the default TSocket which you create has very limited timeout which works in local settings. However for connecting remotely you need to increase the timeout while creating the TSocket.

```
TSocket socket = new TSocket(serverHostName, port, 10000)
```